# How many times can I "recharge" a phosphorescent material? Can an atom run out of its electrons?

Tags: electrons

I have a phosphorescent material and I was wondering how many times I can make it emit light by **recharging** it with light. I roughly know the physics behind it, I've learnt about photo-luminescence and excited energy states so I know what's happening inside an atom when it's emitting photons. Yet, I'd like to know if there is any process which makes the electrons be ejected from the atoms during luminescence.

- So is it possible an atom run out of its electrons therefore my phosphorescent object won't emit light anymore even though I'm trying to excite it with light?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

No the electrons are not leaving the atoms, they are just lowering states(when emitting light). Due to complicated Quantum Configurations(States) and the Kinetics of recombination/relaxation, the energy is released very slowly.